# how to add PHPExcel library in laravel?

Tags: laravel-4, phpexcel

i want to create new module in laravel which include PHPExcel library. where to put library. how to access it.

i have put the PHPExcel library at below location

```
laravel\project\application\libraries\PHPEXCEL
```

it give me error
PHP Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel' not found.

Comment: I had the same question and answered me, I leave the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764375/how-i-can-install-the-phpexcel-library-in-laravel

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [PHPExcel Composer package](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel). Just add `"phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-master"` to your `composer.json` and enter `composer update`. This way the library will be "installed" and you can use it as normal (for example `$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();`) No need for manual includes etc.

**Update may 2016**

Instead of editing your `composer.json`, please use the 'official' command:

`composer require phpoffice/phpexcel`

Answer (score 1):

Below are the step to use PHPEXCEL Library with laravel 5

1:- Install "phpoffice" Package in Laravel 5. Below is the link for the packages

2:- Add "phpexcel/phpexcel": "dev-master" to your composer.json. Ex:- "require": { "phpexcel/phpexcel": "dev-master" }

3:- Then execute "composer update".

4:- Open the file "/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php". Paste the below line in the file.

// Include PHPEXCEL Library with Laravel 5 
 'PHPExcel' => array($vendorDir . '/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes'),

5:- Now you can use PHPEXCEL library in your controllers or middleware or library. use PHPExcel; use PHPExcel_IOFactory;

For more details you can access "https://github.com/pantlavanya/export-to-excel-using-phpoffice-phpexcel-in-laravel-5" link.

Comment: Wow, this is a _very_ bad way of adding the package! Never, ever edit files in your `vendor` directory! Composer will manage this for you

Comment: Hi Trizz, Thanks for your comment. You are right ! Composer will manage this for us. But if we are not able to use PHPEXCEL Library after installing with composer we can check manually. It happened with me when i was installing PHPEXCEL library on Shared Hosting. So i achieve it with this method.