# How to install/clone PHPExcel library in laravel?

Tags: laravel, package, phpexcel

I'm trying to use this library to create excel files but i can't. When i'm trying to install it then show this message...  [Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764375/how-i-can-install-the-phpexcel-library-in-laravel)

**Failed to clone https://github.com/ddeboer/phpexcel.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.**
[Failed Message Image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uWrz.jpg)

Comment: Duplicate for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130008/how-to-add-phpexcel-library-in-laravel/35081440#35081440

Answer (score 0):

Kamruzzaman Khondakar

Looking at their [website](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=phpexcel), the project has been migrated to this [repo](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) on github.

Also, looking at that [repo](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), the docs say the project has been deprecated and users should use this [new one](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).